# Data manipulation and sending it with Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I just started working with Azure last week and I'm wondering if it is possible to create a system that revolves around Azure Logic App. So, I'm generating data using python and somehow send the data to Azure Blobs Storage or SharePoint and make the same AzLogic App to extract some of the columns and rows of that data, map the extracted data, and generate a new CSV file, then use the same Logic App to upload the file to an SFTP server?

I have done this in the past using AWS. For example, I could embed a kinesis end-point or hardcoded access and secret keys on my python data generator and the script will send the data to S3 and uses AWS Glue to perform and ETL and uses the same Glue to send it to a different S3 bucket. But, I'm not sure if it is achievable to do that in Azure. Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use logic app connectors. 
for reading files from blob use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage

performing some data operation use Controls and loop through the data

For CSV, you can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations

and saving that file to SFTP server, you can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-sftp-ssh